# Pair with MZ220

Tags: bluetooth, zebra-printers

I have recently got a portable printer MZ 220. However i am not able to pair with it, i have looked everywhere in the manual to try get the pin and i have tried 1234 and 0000..??

Comment: It's unlikely anyone will know what printer you're talking about unless you give the name of the manufacturer. I've never heard of an "MZ220". Also, what part of this do you think is [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Comment: its a zebra printer sorry should have mentioned in the title, i did but it in the tags. And its a programming printer, it has its own programming language.

Comment: If you're using Android, also check out Zebra's mobile SDK  --  zebra.com/sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set up an autorisation code on the printer.
standard the printer dont have a pin code.

you can't pair with android becouse android requires a pin.

use Lable vista to set up the printer.

also look in the document's of zebra they have described it somwere.

Comment: Excellent thanks, downloaded label vista and set the authentication on and set it the pin thanks